# Map network drive and provide an alias

Tags: windows, network-shares

I am running a batch file that automatically maps a network drive on start up using the "net use" command:

```
net use d:\\server\share <mypassword> /user:<user>
```

This works fine as the result in Windows Explorer shows:

```
\\server\share (D:)
```

I would like to give the share a different name though. Is there a way to provide some sort of alias in the `net use` command for the network mapped drive?

Comment: Try this `subst i: d:\`

Comment: where does this fit in with the above net use command?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't fit in net use command, but might help to use after it as a separate command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want some sort of friendly label on the drive, so rather than saying "**\\server\share**," it says "**Sales Reports**" or whatever is in the share.  Here's how you do it.

```
set driveUNC=\\server.domain.local\ShareName

REM Map the network drive.
net use * %driveUNC%

REM Alter the string a bit to come up with the registry key name.
set driveUNC=%driveUNC:\=#%

REM Change the drive's label in the registry.
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\%driveUNC%" /v  "_LabelFromDesktopINI" /t REG_SZ /d "Drive Label Goes Here" /f
```