# logon script to map network drive

Tags: windows, script, network-shares, domain

I am trying to hide network path of shared folders from domain users. (windows 2013)
I have found this script  while searching for network drive labeling.

```
$a = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$a.NameSpace( "H:\" ).self.name = "Network Drive "
```

If I run the script by opening power shell manually , it successfully labels the network share and hides to network path from user.

Please guide me how to make it  a logon script , so that when user logs in , this script will run and his/her network drive will be renamed.

I have no idea about windows scripting.  so i will be needing step by step help to make it work.

Comment: There is no Windows 2013. [Assign User Logon Scripts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908(v=ws.11).aspx), I'm not certain you can use PS out of the box for it. In addition you could always dump a script on the machine and add it to Autostart.

Comment: its active directory with 500+ machines , Very hard to as it to assgin it to autostart on individual pc.

Comment: Why would it be hard to use your software deployment to do it? In addition the article points out the involved GPO to setup a login/logoff script. You would just have to put it on a share that's available for the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have **PowerShell** logic that works as you confirmed and you just need to know how to get it to work from the login script, just append the logic example I provide below with your logic as needed. Just be sure that your logic to map the drives is run before this logic runs.

I provided the [Setting up a Logon Script through Active Directory Users and Computers](https://www.petri.com/setting-up-logon-script-through-active-directory-users-computers-windows-server-2008)   that you can review for more indepth detail of setting up a login script which is a relatively simple task.

If you're using a batch script, just append the logic to the end of the process as shown below. If you're using a VB Script, then see [Run a VBScript file](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-run.html) here to see the `objShell.Run "c:\batch\test.cmd"` example but you'd create and point it to `\\DomainController\sysvol\<domain>\scripts\<Batch>.cmd`

**Example Batch Login Script**

*I tested and confirmed that this works as expected in a domain environment on a Windows PC with a login script from a domain user account.*

```
<your existing batch login script logic up here>
<you will ensure the logic to map the drives has already been run>

SET TmpPSScript=%Temp%\~tmp_RenameDrive.ps1
IF EXIST "%TmpPSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO $a = New-Object -ComObject shell.application >>"%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO $a.NameSpace( "H:\" ).self.name = "Homes"    >>"%TmpPSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%TmpPSScript%'"

EXIT
```

---

### Additional Resources

- [Setting up a Logon Script through Active Directory Users and Computers](https://www.petri.com/setting-up-logon-script-through-active-directory-users-computers-windows-server-2008)
- [Run a VBScript file](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-run.html)
- [Map network drive and provide alias](https://superuser.com/questions/528836/map-network-drive-and-provide-alias/528860#528860)

Comment: Sadia - Additionally I wanted to add since you're in an AD domain environment, you could use Group Policy Preferences to map network drives based on security group membership which has a "label" field that does this same for of thing for a mapped network drive on Windows OSes. I've used this method and it works solidly and once setup it's just a matter of adding the user account(s) you wish to have it to the security group.Here's a tutorial with screen shot, etc. from 2009 but it appears to be applicable still from what I can tell settings wise with GPP and AD.